# Issue in Global.asax.cs page in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I my ASP.NET MVC 4 Project, my `Global.asax.cs` page shows the error on

```
 WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

> **The name 'GlobalConfiguration' does not exist in the current context**

I have done many controllers and Views and all... How can I solve this issue and recover my project?

Here is the rest of my code for context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace .....
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the namespace for that class.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Make sure you have assembly `System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll` referenced. This is where GlobalConfiguration is.

Comment: My issue was with AreaRegistration. The above didn't work for me; however, NuGet "update all packages" did work. HTH.

Comment: Force remove and install worked for me. Pretty fast.

Answer (score 61):

With .NET Framework 4.5.1, GlobalConfiguration is found in `System.Web.Http`:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me with .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Yup. That did it!  Same framework as @NickMasao

Answer (score 22):

`Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost -reinstall`

This worked for me. I was facing issues with the reference not being updated correctly on Update-package or even removing and installing the package again.

The above command reinstalls all dependencies, and usually does the trick whenever I face nuget package reference issue.

Comment: WOW! I've been banging my had in the wall for hours. Didn't imagine it could be so easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also try doing the opposite (no offense) to what David Bohunek suggests.  I tried Davids suggestion to no avail.   Then I would up removing that reference that was referenced directly in the "Assemblies" section.

Then I removed the Web Api 2.2 and Web Api 2.2 Web Host Nugets, performed a clean and then JUST added back the Web Api 2.2 Web Host NuGet.

Try that.  Good luck,  it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my asp.net webform based on 4.5, adding System.Web.Routing dll and below import in global.aspx resolved the problem

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Http" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted most of the fixes listed above to no avail. I am sure 9 out of 10 are normally resolved by the posts above but for this error, but none of these helped me.

My fix for this error, was that I was renaming my namespace and had two different references to the namespace which in the end caused my issue. Since I wanted to update the namespace with something other than I started with, I ended up fixing this issue by changing my namespace to the newer one in my `WebApiConfig.cs`. Apparently it was one of the last files which I hadn't used the newer namespace name.

Well, once I changed that then my errors went away. Also, another fix for this same issue was to specify `using old namespace name;` which also fixed it temporarily which got me to just rename it in the `WebApiConfig.cs` with the new name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting a similar issue in Glabal.asax:

```
The name 'AreaRegistration' does not exist in the current context.
```

I already had `System.Web.Mvc` namespace in `Global.asax.cs` but the compiler was somewhat not aware of it, that is, the `AreaRegistration` class was not being found.

What fixed the issue was executing the following command in [`Package Manager Console`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console) inside Visual Studio:

```
PM> Update-Package -reinstall
```

After NuGet reinstalled all the project's packages, the missing class names appeared and the code built successfully.

Something is broken in Visual Studio\NuGet restore pipeline...