# WebApiConfig error in Global.asax

Tags: c#

Please have a look at my Global.asax, i put the "problem" in caps. When I try to build, I get `"The name 'WebApiConfig' does not exist in the current context`

What am I missing, I´ve added the nuget `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost`

```
using SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace SportsStore.WebUI
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WEBAPICONFIG.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new
            NinjectControllerFactory());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: [Issue in Global.asax.cs page in MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402081/issue-in-global-asax-cs-page-in-mvc4)

Comment: Thank you, however, this takes care of the GlobalConfiguration-part...It does not affect the Webconfig..

Comment: I solved by creating the webapiconfig from this page:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/configuring-aspnet-web-api

Comment: im trying to do the same thing  as shown  but i can't  get it right

Answer (score 6):

The WebApiConfig class is normally created under App_Start if you choose to add Web API references when creating a new ASP.NET web app in visual studio.

Manually add the class if it's not present:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```